# How to separate two items of same column into two columns?

Tags: mysql, sql

`ColorBreakdown`:

| id | color | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | red | 25 |
| 0 | blue | 13 |
| 1 | red | 16 |
| 1 | blue | 17 |

`Color`:

| name |
| --- |
| red |
| blue |

How do I separate the two into table below without altering tables (by selecting, joining, filtering, etc.)?

| id | red | blue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 25 | 13 |
| 0 | 16 | 17 |

I tried:

```
SELECT id, c.amount
FROM Color
INNER JOIN ColorBreakdown AS c ON (Color.name = ColorBreakdown.color);
```

It only gives `red` color for each `id`:

| id | c.amount |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 25 |
| 0 | 16 |

Then I tried:

```
SELECT id, 
       SUM(color = 'red') AS red, 
       SUM(color = 'blue') AS blue
FROM ColorBreakdown
GROUP BY id;
```

But it gave:

| id | red | blue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 |

Comment: Your second query needs a GROUP BY to run.

Comment: Thank you, it works now but not the way that I intended it to still :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `group by` and `case` to achieve this

a sample query is something like :

```
SELECT id, 
       sum(case when color = 'red' then amount else 0 end) AS red,
       sum(case when color = 'blue' then amount else 0 end) AS blue
FROM ColorBreakdown
group by id;
```